# Clear certain Windows Prefetch files without a trace with Python or Batch files

Tags: python, batch-file, prefetch

I need to remove around 5 .pf Prefetch files without leaving a trace. The problem is that when I remove them using a "del" statment in a bat file, or a os.remove in python, a new entry in the prefetch is made that is either CMD-xxxxxx.pf or PYTHON.EXE-xxxxxxxx.pf.

I know it might be confusing, but I really need those files to not be created in the prefetch folder, and i can not manually delete them either for certain reasons. I also can not delete the entire prefetch. Sorry that I cannot provide an explanation but its important that its done this way.

This is how the code is looking now.

```
@echo off
cls
title Cleaner
@RD /S /Q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp\jna-1181626897"
@RD /S /Q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp\jna"
del C:\Windows\Prefetch\CSCRIPT.EXE-86862D5C.pf
del C:\Windows\Prefetch\WMIPRVSE.EXE-606B6550.pf
del C:\Windows\Prefetch\SEARCHFILTERHOST.EXE-AA802AE6.pf
del C:\Windows\Prefetch\SEARCHPROTOCOLHOST.EXE-80E6FA72.pf
```

It's pretty much identical in python only using the "os.remove" instead of "del".

I have also tried deleting the new .pf files in the code, but it only recreates them before it closes.

Comment: Would `powershell "[IO.File]::Delete(\"filename.pf\")"` work?  That's the .NET equivalent of C++ `_unlink()` [according to the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c3tczd6.aspx).  Of course, the difference between unlinking and deleting a file is probably not as significant with NTFS as with a Unix inode table, so there may be no difference.  You could also try compiling a small C# program to perform the deleting I suppose.  \*shrug\*  I'm just making wild guesses here.

Comment: going to try it soon, thanks for the advice :)